# CSS "cut away" sides of a image and fill background of webpage

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have an image and am asked to copy the example given to me. currently, I am placing the background image and have noticed the example they have given me has given or taken, 100px from the top, and 300px from the bottom taken away (I could only guess the correct vocabulary to be cropped). I have attempted to use :

```
body {
  background-image: url("stuffNthings.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

but have found that using this block the image is centered as far to the top right corner as possible and missing more than 300px from the bottom. the right side appears correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to know what this example you're given is but `background-position` property might be good in this case.

It will align the image to the right horizontally (I assume that's what you want since you say the right side of the image looks correct) and push it vertically up 100px (and will hopefully leave 300px at the bottom, it depends on the size of an image, but unless the page will be seen on a single size screen and not be responsive, I wouldn't worry about that).

```
body {
  background-position: right -100px;
}
```

Check out [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for more info

Comment: ya, that sounds like an appropriate solution if I use `background-position: x y` and make y a negative. but I think you misunderstand the 300 pix at the bottom. I would like to cut off about 300px from the bottom of the image.

Comment: I think i need to use `background-size` somehow